# JavaScript, I am making an ajax request and I need help going through the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function wrong(word){

 $("#main-display").html("");
 $("#main-display").append("Sorry that is not a valid word");


var word = "lighht";
var check = "https://montanaflynn-spellcheck.p.mashape.com/check/?text=" + word;

// Ajax request to wordsapi 
// Will return the synonyms of the searched word
$.ajax({
    url: check, // The URL to the API. You can get this in the API page of the API you intend to consume
    type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method, can be GET POST PUT DELETE etc
    data: {}, // Additional parameters here
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { console.dir((data.source)); console.log(data);},
    error: function(err) { wrong(word) },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    console.log(check);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "key"); // Enter here your Mashape key
    }



}).done(function(response){
    console.log(word);
    console.log(response);
    var hey = Object.keys(response.corrections);
    console.log(hey);
    console.log(response.corrections +".lighht");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(Object.keys(response.corrections.lighht));
    }

}); // End of ajax of synonyms
```

So I am trying to make a function that returns possible choices of a words base on the word the user entered. I found an API that works great but I am having a hard time trying to get it the data on the screen.  The JSON object looks like this:

The main problem I am having is that object key of "lighht" is going to change based on the word. So when I try to make it a variable like:

```
{
  "original": "lighht",
  "suggestion": "light",
  "corrections": {
    "lighht": [
      "light",
      "sleight",
      "hightail",
      "alright",
      "Bligh",
      "Lhotse",
      "Galahad"
    ]
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(response.corrections.word[i]));
```

It doesn't work and breaks.

So I need to know how to get this data.

Comment: `corrections` doesn't have a property called `word`

Comment: I know that but it I need it to be a variable base on the user choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery so you can just use `$.each()`:

```js
var response = {
  "original": "lighht",
  "suggestion": "light",
  "corrections": {
    "lighht": [
      "light",
      "sleight",
      "hightail",
      "alright",
      "Bligh",
      "Lhotse",
      "Galahad"
    ],
    "cooool": [
      "cool",
      "car"
    ]
  }
};

// If you want to iterate over all of the corrections:
$.each(response.corrections, function(c) {
  console.log(response.corrections[c]);
});

var userInput = 'cooool';

// Access an individual item:
console.log(response.corrections[userInput]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop

```js
var response = {
  "original": "lighht",
  "suggestion": "light",
  "corrections": {
    "lighht": [
      "light",
      "sleight",
      "hightail",
      "alright",
      "Bligh",
      "Lhotse",
      "Galahad"
    ]
  }
}


$.each(response.corrections, function(v) {
      console.log(v);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```